# How to forward subdomain host to proxypass with Apache?

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy

My node server is listening at `127.0.0.1:7676`. However, it responds differently depending on the subdomain. With a standard `ProxyPass` config (below), the subdomain is stripped.

How can I forward the subdomain to the node server?

**Example 1: Basic Proxy Config:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias *.example.com

    ProxyPass / http://localhost:7676/

</VirtualHost>
```

**Example 2: An Attempt to pass a simply "test" subdomain for all requests**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias *.example.com

    RequestHeader set "Host" "test.example.com"
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:7676/

</VirtualHost>
```

My attempt (example 2) doesn't work. The node server still sees no subdomains. And even if it did work, I need it to be dynamic (take whatever subdomain is requested and pass it to the node server).

Please note, there can be multiple subdomains (`test2.test1.example.com`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some trial and error I figured it out.

The issue with Example 2, is that instead of setting the "Host" header, Apache decides to implicitly set the "X-Forwarded-Host" header. Honestly, I would have rather it error instead of silently setting a different header, but alright.

However, in order to forward the host (take whatever subdomain is requested and pass it to the node server), we can use Apache's handy dandy `ProxyPreserveHost On`, documented [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypreservehost).

This will set the "X-Forwarded-Host" to the requested host.

---

The following is implmentation dependent. I used Node with Express.

The following is how I implemented the check:

```
function getSubDomains(host, offset = 2) {
    const split = host.split(".").reverse();
    return split.slice(2);
}

router.all('*', function (req, res, next) {
    const subdomains = getSubDomains(req.get("X-Forwarded-Host"));
    // code to use subdomains
```

Are you asking why I didn't just overwrite `req.subdomains`? For some reason it didn't work so I just went with this.

Lastly, I added a quick check to make sure the domain is mine. This probably isn't necessary tho.

```
function getSubDomains(host, offset = 2) {
    const split = host.split(".").reverse();
    if (split[0] !== "com" || split[1] !== "example") { // for *.example.com
        return false;
    }
    return split.slice(2);
}


router.all('*', function (req, res, next) {
    const subdomains = getSubDomains(req.get("X-Forwarded-Host"));
    if (!subdomains) {
        res.send("Huh?");
        return;
    }
```

Comment: `ProxyPreserveHost On` should set `Host` header.

Comment: @DusanBajic It did not for me. It set X-Forwarded-Host